# is it possible to generate HTML 5 page from XML data?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, dynamic-pages

I have data coming from a server in pure XML format, but I want to render the output as a rich HTML 5 page for the user. I got to use only client side scripting for this purpose (that too just Javascript).

So, is it possible to generate HTML-5 page using XML data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to transform the xml. That's exactly that its for and all major browsers support them, including IE6.

Otherwise, you could have a bare HTML with just a `<head>` and a `<body>` with jQuery and some JS wizardry.

Answer (score 2):

Look over here. 
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-and-XML/

Answer (score 2):

Newer browers can parse XML

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

So it should be possible to parse the XML in the browser, and then write code to take the model and render it as you see fit.